# How can I convert a list of binary 0 to 1 numbers PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

How can I convert a  list of binary 0 to 1 numbers in Prolog to give me the following results:

```erlang
?- cryptoA( [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1], L2).
L2 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Simple, it's

```erlang
cryptoA([1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]).
```

But of course it's too specific. More cases should probably be added, like

```erlang
cryptoA([1,1,0,1,0,0,0],   [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]  ).
cryptoA([1,1,0,1,0,0],     [0,0,1,0,1,1]    ).
cryptoA([1,1,0,1,0],       [0,0,1,0,1]      ).
.....
cryptoA([1,1,0],           [0,0,1]          ).
.....
cryptoA([  1  ],           [  0  ]          ).
cryptoA([    0],           [    1]          ).
```

right? But how many concrete cases is enough? Is it ever going to be, enough?

To deal with the infinite number of structured cases, we can write down a structured code, using recursion. The last two clauses seem minimal, and why should they be enclosed in lists like that?

```erlang
cryptoB(   1 ,                0             ).
cryptoB(     ,                              ).         
                               % fill the blanks
```

What is the recursive case?

```erlang
cryptoA( [A | B], [C | D] ) :-
  cryptoB(  ,  ),              % fill the blanks
  cryptoA( B, D).
```

What is the base case?

```erlang
cryptoA( [    ], [    ] ).     % fill the blanks
```

Finishing the last clause's definition is particularly easy.

---

We could arrive at this "recursive" solution by the same way of playing with the given example, simplifying it, and then *generalizing* it.

Let's see. Going in another direction, it is

```erlang
cryptoA(  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0],   [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]  ).   % which means this must hold:
cryptoA(  [  1,0,1,0,0,0],   [  0,1,0,1,1,1]  ).   % and also this must hold:
cryptoA(  [1            ],   [0            ]  ).   % which is to say,
cryptoB(   1             ,    0               ).   % this must hold
```

So, let's write this down!

```erlang
cryptoA(  [1,1,0,1,0,0,0],   [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]  ) :-
  cryptoA([  1,0,1,0,0,0],   [  0,1,0,1,1,1]  ),
  cryptoB( 1             ,    0               ).

%% or, equivalently,
cryptoA( X,   Y  ) :- 
  X =     [1,1,0,1,0,0,0],  Y = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1],   % specific case
  X =     [A | B        ],  Y = [C | D        ],   % general structure
  cryptoA(     B,                    D        ),   %  recursive step
  cryptoB( A             ,       C            ).   %  single-step processing
```

and now, we can generalize by simply removing that specific case definition. Surely the same scheme must hold with any other specific data at all!

Of course not every list can be matched up with a *non-empty list* `[_ | _]` pattern, just because not *all* lists are non-empty. Some lists are actually empty, `[]`, and this gives rise to the base case.

Lastly, the recursive step is preferred to be specified last, in so called *tail* position, for the overall predicate to be *tail* recursive. It is much more efficient this way.

Answer (score 2):

one to one correspondence in lists is easily done with maplist:

```erlang
cryptoA(A,B) :- maplist(\X^Y^(X=1,Y=0;X=0,Y=1),A,B).
```

You should install library(lambda) for this to work, in SWI-Prolog for instance

```erlang
?- pack_install(lambda).
```

Comment: @false: thanks, noted. Hope a lambda expression fits better.

Comment: or you could just name it with an adjective, e.g. `inverted_bits/2`.